# Init script changes for MongoDB

Tags: init, pid, mongodb

We have MongoDB (Version 3.0) in production in standalone as well as in cluster mode. Currently we were facing issue that basically states:

> Unclean shutdown detected hence unable to start mongod.

1. After debugging we got to know mongod was showing different pid in (O/p of ps -> i.e

```
ps -eo pid,cmd | grep "/usr/bin/mongod" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $1}') and there was different pid in /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid.
```

2. In second scenario testing team performed multiple restart operations in that case we got situation where mongod was in running state but pid file were missing.

For 1st scenario we simply changed init script to check if running PID is different than PID present in `mongod.pid` then simply write running PID inside `mongod.pid` file.

Any help to understand these scenarios will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few reasons why this can happen, including [this bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18977) which sounds quite close to your situation (and is fixed in a later build of 3.0 according to the ticket).

There is also the fact that some daemonization processes require that the process be started with [fork=false](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#processManagement.fork) in order to work properly and get the PID right, see [SERVER-7254](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7254) for more there.

Those are the two most likely causes, would probably need more specific information (exact version of MongoDB, OS etc.) to try to reproduce for anything else.